# Is it possible to index a child (nested) collection of an apex:repeat collection using apex:variable?

Tags: visualforce

In a Visualforce page, I have an `apex:repeat` iterating over a `List<List<a Class>>`, and I want to index the **current** nested list using an apex:variable. Prefer not to use two nested apex:repeats for requirement reasons.

In its simplest form:

```
<apex:variable var="scheduleIndex" value="0"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!revenueSchedules}" var="revSched">

    // I want to do something like this, where scheduleIndex is the
    apex:variable and NameString is some property of the List returned
    by revSched.scheduleIndex:

    <apex:outputfield value="{!revSched}.scheduleIndex.{NameString}"> 
    </apex:outputField>
    <apex:variable var="scheduleIndex" value="{!scheduleIndex + 1}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Is this possible with just Visualforce, i.e. can we index the current iteration of apex:repeat and simply read properties? I prefer to not modify the controller, although it's looking like that's where I'll have to go.

Comment: Try `value="{!revSched[scheduleIndex].SomeRealName}"` You can access a  list index using variable for sure. I am not sure about accessing a class property using a variable. I think you need to give a real property name explicitly.

Comment: This is possible, however it is not recommended. Mutating variables inside repeat tags using Visualforce can result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an index, consider making a list of indexes and iterating over *that* instead:

```
public Integer[] getIndexArray() {
    Integer[] results = new Integer[0];
    while(results.size() < someArray.size()) results.add(results.size());
    return results;
}
```

You can then loop over this:

```
<apex:repeat var="index" value="{!indexArray}">
    <apex:outputField value="{!someArray[index].Name}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

You can technically use an index using apex:variable, but the documentation states it is not supported. I have successfully used this in trivial pages, though, so it's entirely possible:

```
<apex:variable name="index" value="{!0}" />
<apex:repeat ...>
    <!-- other stuff here -->
    <apex:variable name="index" value="{!index+1}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

This isn't always guaranteed to work, but may work in some trivial cases.