# Indexing a PROPERTY of the current iteration during <apex:repeat>

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

This is a follow up question to this question: [Is it possible to index a child (nested) collection of an apex:repeat collection using apex:variable?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72168/is-it-possible-to-index-a-child-nested-collection-of-an-apexrepeat-collection)

I've been stuck on this for two days. I'm beginning to think it's impossible. It's fundamentally indexing a 2D array, with some constraints that appear to make it impossible in this context.

### Scenario:

I have an `<apex:repeat>` that is iterating over `List<RevenueSchedule>`.

`RevenueSchedule` is a class that has a property called `schedules`, which is a `List<SomeObject>`.

I need to be able to index `schedules`, and retrieve a Double field called revenue from the `SomeObject` at that index of schedules, all in the context of our outer `<apex:repeat>` over `List<RevenueSchedule>`.

Here is a summary of the object structure, for clarity:

What the `<apex:repeat>` is looping over:

```
List<RevenueSchedule>
```

RevenueSchedule:

```
public class RevenueSchedule {
    private List<SomeObject> schedules;
}
```

SomeObject:

```
public class SomeObject {
    private Double revenue;
}
```

**The design constraint is this**: I have to build this out by rows. Each row contains a date and two revenues for that date, so they are logically coupled. Thus, I have to build a column for a list of dates, and then a column for each RevenueSchedule (let's say arbitrarily that there are two). They must be side-by-side, and this  is already nested within another apex:repeat that builds out rows, one for each date in a year. This is why I have to be able to select an **individual** Double, because I build this div structure out by ROWS. It looks like this:

```
Date         RevSched1                             RevSched2
Mar '15      RevSched1.schedules[row1].revenue     RevSched1.schedules[row1].revenue
Apr '15      RevSched1.schedules[row2].revenue     RevSched1.schedules[row2].revenue
May '15      RevSched1.schedules[row3].revenue     RevSched1.schedules[row3].revenue
```

**This will compile** - it will print a List of IDs...but does not go "deep" enough into the structure that I need:

```
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber"/> 
<apex:repeat value="{!revenueSchedules}" var="revSched"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{!revSched.schedules}">
    </apex:outputText>
```

Here is what the above code renders: 
[image]

Here is the Visualforce code that logically would do what I want, but it fails to compile (syntax error):

```
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber"/> 
<apex:repeat value="{!revenueSchedules}" var="revSched"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{!revSched.schedules[rowNumber].revenue}">
    </apex:outputText>
```

In a perfect world, I would be able to call some parametrized function in the controller such as `returnIndexedRevenue(Integer rowNumber, Integer colNumber)`, but I don't think that's possible in Visualforce - only getters and setters.

Hopefully I've been thorough enough. Let me know if there's anything I can make more clear, I am open to any suggestions. I didn't write the controller for this page, and it's 1000+ lines long, so I was hoping to find an easy solution to this without modifying too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remodel your code to use a collection for each row, like

```
public class RevenueScheduleRow {
    public DateTime Date {get;set};
    public List<SomeObject> schedules {get;set};
}
```

And visualforce code can have a repeat inside first repeat, something like (uncompiled code):-

```
<apex:repeat value="{!revenueSchedules}" var="revSched"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{!revSched.Date}"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!revSched.schedules}" var="sched">
        <apex:outputText value="{!sched.revenue}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: It turns out it was impossible to achieve what I wanted in the question, given my parameters and how the existing code was structured. I ended up rendering them in columns, but I'm accepting your answer because the only way to do what I wanted was to restructure the code, as you suggested.